# What is wrong with my question and how could I have done it better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I was reading the [meta post on coping with downvotes](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11444/coping-with-downvotes) in which [ColleenV made an excellent point](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11446/299653) about how receiving multiple downvotes warrants a closer look at the post in question.

Earlier today I posted [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448758/single-word-verb-for-to-do-from-scratch), which has since gotten two downvotes (both of which were received after the two edits I made for clarity). I tried examining the question myself but was unable to find anything wrong with it.

As such, I would appreciate any input pertaining to how I could have done it better.

**Addressing existing criticisms**:
 Some criticisms that were received as comments in the question include (1) why I couldn't just use multiple words and (2) that the question was trivial.

I'd argue the first point is not a valid fault with the question because single-word requests are one of the most common topics on this platform and it's not like I was asking for a bizarrely specific concept. For the record, I did provide an explanation as to why I wanted a single word, but the impetus for a question shouldn't impact it's validity.

The user who made the second point apparently did not understand the question as the suggested "obvious" answer was not valid.

Comment: SWR questions are a very controversial issue on this site. There are users who would happily ban such requests from this site because they think they generally are poor quality questions of quiz-like nature. Anyway one way to improve a question, any question, is to show your research  by adding links to dictionaries explaining  why your findings don’t answer your question. In your case you could google “from scratch” and look for synonyms and see what the results are.

Comment: @user3850720 I see. I didn't know that they were controversial, and now that I do I won't ask any more here. As for research, there really isn't much that you can do. For example, your suggestion of searching for synonyms of *from scratch* (which I did and interestingly there isn't a good single-word replacement) wouldn't solve the problem because the question is about the verb phrase ***do** from scratch* so just finding replacements for the adverb doesn't help.

Comment: Well, the points you are making  now, if included in your original post, would have helped understand the nature of your question and possibly attracted less objections. Always show your “research efforts” and explain why they didn’t bring the results you are looking for. BTW, I am personally in favour of SWR questions.

Comment: I guess I assumed that that much would be understood. But my main issue is nobody pointed out that the question wasn't appropriate for EL&U, which would have been a valid point. Rather, they either (1) misunderstood the question despite explicit warnings about the misunderstanding or (2) attacked the impetus of the question, which is completely unrelated. Also, to be honest, I suspect it was a single user who used a secondary account to downvote my question (and upvote the comment posted by the main account) because the 2 downvotes (and comment upvote) happened almost simultaneously.

Comment: But that's besides the point. If the community here doesn't find SWR questions appropriate (which I find odd given how it is the most used tag on this SE) then I'll take them elsewhere. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: The question is appropriate as long as you post your research. The fact that a number of user don’t like SWR questions doesn’t make them off-topic and as a matter of fact SWR questions are regularly posted.

Comment: Downvotes and misunderstandings are just part of the game. Don’t feel too frustrated about that. You don’t need to.

Comment: @Zachary "*Also, to be honest, I suspect it was a single user who used a secondary account to downvote my question (and upvote the comment posted by the main account) because the 2 downvotes (and comment upvote) happened almost simultaneously.*" If you **believe** that's the case, custom mod flag it and ask for an investigation because that's an **abuse**. Otherwise, better not to assume anything.

Comment: @AndrewT. Are moderators able to see who made the downvote? Because if they can't then there's nothing much they can investigate. But if they can it should be obvious because I imagine the secondary account's primary activity would involve up and downvoting comments, questions, and answers the primary user is involved in.

Comment: @Zachary moderators can't, but they can escalate the issue to SE staff to investigate further.

Comment: @AndrewT. Then it's not worth it. I do believe that it is true because (1) two downvotes and one convenient upvote occured way too close for me to believe it was a coincidence and (2) I really don't see why anyone (other than the user) would upvote the comment because it--to be frank--was a really bad answer. But just because I believe it doesn't mean I think it's worth the moderators', SE staff's, and my time. If it is true then I feel sorry for that person. If it's not true then there's nothing to say. To be honest, I already feel stupid enough letting such a small thing affect me so much.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Enough. There's been at least two times when I almost asked a question, but I researched and found the answer myself first.

Comment: @curiousdannii but sometimes it's good to hold back everything you know in a new question because the answers may pleasantly surprise you, and teach you and all of us something new.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, but I don't want to contribute to the problem of lazy questions, and once I've done my homework I don't know how to ask a question that would pass our site standards so that I could then self answer it.

Comment: @curiousdannii but you've never asked a question on EL&U in your life! How can one question by a linguist, such as yourself,  possibly be "lazy"? So you know everything? Wow :) You should be answering more questions then (I'm teasing) :D

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's lazy if I don't look for an answer myself first, just like everyone else. I don't know everything by far, but so far I've been able to find answers when I have thought of questions. But then I don't know how to still phrase it such that it would be acceptable. Because I would have to post my research, and that research would contain the answer.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ If I had a SWR that would be a type of question I probably wouldn't find an answer to, but I'm not creative enough to need SWRs. As to answering more questions, well I probably should. But it's hard to find the good ones...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for your input! Just a few things: (1) I agree that providing some evidence of research is a good idea, but I don't see why a user has to provide the reason for SWRs. You don't question a user asking about, say, the etymology of a word why they want to know that, right? If the question doesn't interest you (generic *you*, of course) or you don't see why someone would want to ask it, just ignore it because that doesn't automatically make it a bad question.

Comment: Sometimes a word does not exist but we often get similar requests e.g.:  *I need the word that means "the niece of my ex-husband's youngest sister-in-law"*  and also *"What's a single word for feeling disappointed but happy at the same time?"* A human and natural response is to ask "why?" :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA (2) Just to clarify, are you saying that my question was very clearly off-topic (*Your explanation, which by the way, I think requests for naming things (programming) is off-topic, was very clear.*)? Because if that's the case, I never asked for a name in the question; I just asked for a single-word verb that means "to do from scratch". In fact, I no longer *need* it for whatever I was doing, but I still want to ask the question out of curiosity: for such a ubiquitous concept, is it really the case that there isn't a single lexeme for it? And it turns out there is: *bootstrap*!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree that it's natural to ask why, and I'm not saying people shouldn't ask, but I don't think it should be a requirement either. I mean the same goes for etymology questions, right? Most people asking about where a word comes from wants to know for the sake of knowing, so why can't the same apply to SWRs?

Comment: @Mari-LouA "*I need to label ...*" is the **impetus** behind my asking for the word, not the question itself. And that is why I didn't include it in the original question; it doesn't add to the question but detracts from it (the last thing I want is people giving me camel case terms or other naming suggestions)--I just want to know if there's a word for what seems to be a very common concept. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the reason naming requests are frowned upon is because they're too personal and others don't benefit from it. But my question was phrased as a general SWR.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think there's a misunderstanding. First, I'm not using the term in anything related to computer engineering; I'm using it in a paper on educational policy (or "*was* using"--I've gone with something else). Secondly, dictionary.com defines it as a non-technical term meaning "to help (oneself) without the aid of others", even providing this example: *She spent years bootstrapping herself through college.* Thirdly, as I mentioned to another user, it doesn't matter if the term isn't widely known; if we're only allowed to use terms at least 80% of people know reading would be so dry :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78379/discussion-between-zachary-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: @Zachary - RE: _to be honest, I suspect it was a single user who used a secondary account to downvote my question (and upvote the comment posted by the main account) because the 2 downvotes (and comment upvote) happened almost simultaneously._ I rather doubt that’s the case. There have been plenty of times I downvoted a question shortly after someone else left a comment that echoed my thoughts, and then I upvoted the comment as well. That seems more likely than a sockpuppet doubling one individual’s wrath.

Comment: @J.R. Except in this case the two down and one upvote happened all within a few minutes *only after I criticized the comment that got upvoted*. If that user really though the question was bad they would’ve downvoted it sooner, which they didn’t. Again, all I’m saying is that this is too much of a coincidence for *me*, but if you evaluate the same information and arrive at a different conclusion then there’s nothing much to say.

Comment: @Zachary - I think you're being paranoid. How do you even know when the second downvoter got a look at the question? It could have been right after you made your comment. Beside, Jim (the only person with an upvoted question on your comment) has been here for like 7 years. Based on past contributions, I'd be shocked if he was involved in some kind of petty play like that.

Comment: @J.R. (1) I never said anything about knowing when the second account looked at the question, and like I keep saying, the information I *do* have is enough to convince me. And “could have been” arguments are not substantial; it’s about weighing likelihoods, which I did. (2) The length of time someone’s been here doesn’t say anything about their character. If anything, the kind of person who’d go through the trouble of creating a secondary account would have to be pretty dependent on this community for their self-worth.

Comment: @Zachary - Sheesh. <insert eye-roll here>

Comment: Given the controversy single word requests on EL&U generate sometimes, it is not at all unlikely that two different people independently down-voted in a very short period of time and only one of them agreed with and up-voted the comment.  Even if it was something sock-puppety and nefarious, it's only two down-votes and a question of reasonable quality with an author responding to community feedback can easily overcome the single "extra" down-vote. Down-votes only remove 2 reputation, while up-votes add 5, so you only need one person to appreciate your edits and counter an early pair of DVs.

Comment: @ColleenV - I'm surprised you give any credence at all to the sockpuppet theory. Quite frankly, it's an insult to this community and one of its longer-serving members.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you for your insight on the matter; I appreciate it!

Comment: @J.R. I should have made it more clear that I don't think anyone is using a sock puppet to cast two down-votes. I skimmed the comments, so I didn't realize that someone was actually being accused.  Throwing around accusations like that is counter-productive. The focus should be on making the content better not on figuring out who down-voted. It is certainly Not Nice to toss out unfounded accusations. No community member has access to the tools necessary to support such an accusation, so suspicions should be brought to the attention of the mod team and left at that.

Comment: Related: [How can I write good questions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10621/how-can-i-write-good-questions) and [Should we create a collection of exemplary questions to encourage high-quality ?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10628/could-should-we-create-a-collection-of-exemplary-questions-to-encourage-high-qua?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the following points are very good advice, follow these tips and your question should be "safe" and always appreciated.

> SWR questions are a very controversial issue on this site. There are users who would happily ban such requests from this site because they think they generally are poor quality questions of quiz-like nature. Anyway, **one way to improve a question**, any question, **is to show your research by adding links to dictionaries explaining why your findings didn’t answer your question**.
>
> … **the points you are making now, if included in your original post, would have helped understand the nature of your question and possibly attracted less objections**. Always show your “research efforts” and explain why they didn’t bring the results you are looking for.
>
> In your case, you could google “from scratch” and look for synonyms and see what the results are. [@user3850720](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/what-is-wrong-with-my-question-and-how-could-i-have-done-it-better#comment48634_11465)